# jar files not working

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, jar

In terminal when try to run jar file it doesn't launch. I have recently uninstalled open jdk 6 to save some space if that matters.

```
abe@abe-Dimension-8400:~/Desktop$ java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

I use openjdk-7-jdk-headless java version. Tried re-installing the openjdk-7-jre-headless

```
abe@abe-Dimension-8400:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree    

Reading state information... Done

openjdk-7-jre-headless is already the newest version.
```

Please help Thanks.

Comment: fo1's solution resulted in the same error code.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get any error messages? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: Are you certain that no jar files are working or only Minecraft.jar  is not working.

Comment: Does not work mean the game wont launch nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Setup environment variables.

> You should Setup Environment Variables for java because all of java
>   based application’s use environment variables to work. Open your
>   .bashrc file and add the below coloured line to end of the file. Make
>   sure you need to mention your path instead of us. Save and exit.

This is an example taken from http://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-install-java-7-openjdk-on-ubuntu/

```
magesh@magesh-desktop:~$ nano .bashrc

GNU nano 2.2.6                                    File: .bashrc                                                                              

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:JAVA_HOME:JRE_HOME
```

Comment: I think there is no need to add path for the openjdk version, the java bin file shortcuts are created in usr/bin/ with installation.

Comment: This did not work. anything else?

Comment: Did you try to apt-get autoremove then reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

**headless** jre/jdk means "GUI is not needed and will not work". I suspect you want Minecraft to be GUI-based game. Then you need full jre.

Frankly "does not work" is not a useful symptom. What makes you believe it doesnt? Maybe you expected something and got something different? It's hard to guess.

Comment: Im sorry, when I mean does not work I mean the game does not launch even when I duble click the .jar. I have open jdk 7 fully installed aswell.

Comment: (1) I suggest you to check JAVA_HOME, just having correct PATH is not enough. (2) verify that `java -version` works with correct thing. (3) you are running `jave -jar Minecraft.jar` -- is there Main-Class actually in META-INF/manifest.mf? (4) do you double-click or type command?